# installing package error "sudo apt-get install ppp"

Tags: apt, packages, ppp

I'm trying to install the ppp packaged for the raspberry pi so i can connect a 3g dongle to the internet but i get the following error. It seems that some modules install except one. overall the ppp package doesn't install. How can this error be solved? Thanks!

```
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  javascript-common libc-ares-dev libc-ares2 libev-dev libev4 libv8-3.8.9.20
  libv8-dev node-node-uuid wwwconfig-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ppp
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/351 kB of archives.
After this operation, 651 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 99990 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ppp (from .../ppp_2.4.5-5.1+deb7u2_armhf.deb) ...
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script 'S99runmbbservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runmbbservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service runmbbservice if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and mountnfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and mountall if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 5
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot-bootclean at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 5
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and mountall-bootclean if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall-bootclean at depth 7
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and mountnfs-bootclean if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and mountkernfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service runmbbservice at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service kbd at depth 9
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ppp_2.4.5-5.1+deb7u2_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ppp_2.4.5-5.1+deb7u2_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: So i've solved it. The problem is that there are empty files that should be removed, one of them is runmbbservice,

Comment: Do you have manufacturer's instructions?

Answer (score 4):

Clearly it is showing you that this package is missing dependencies. You need to make sure you update your packages and preferably use a package manager that handles dependencies better. Try this

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo su -
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get update && apt-get install aptitude
root@raspberrypi:~# aptitude upgrade && dpkg --configure -a && aptitude install ppp
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Linux guru but I've be using RPi for a couple years:

Did you did you do sudo apt-update before trying to do your install? I think you want to do this before any kind of upgrade to get the latest package lists so the update process knows where to get all the right stuff.

I would also do "sudo apt-get autoremove" to get rid of those unrequired packages it is telling you about. Why carry around unneeded garbage?

Then, have you done "sudo apt-get upgrade" lately, or are you not doing it intentionally? i.e. from fear of it messing something up? I guess I am in the habit of trying to get the whole system up-to-date before I try to add something new.

Comment: I've just tried that and it doesn't solve it :/ even by removing the unneeded files